# Removing the _ah/upload/ extention from url google app engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

When I upload something in Google cloud storage (through Google App Engine via PHP) using the following

```
$upload_url = CloudStorageTools::createUploadUrl('/upload_handler.php', $options);
```

and

```
<form action="<?php echo $upload_url?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
Files to upload: <br>
<input type="file" name="uploaded_files" size="40">
<input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

The return url contains a _ah/upload/ next to the url

Eg - In this case the return url would be

```
myapp.appspot.com/_ah/upload/
```

And because of this all my includes (JS / CSS / Links) that use relative paths are broken

Eg -

`<a href="assets/demo.doc">Demo Doc</a>` now points to `<a href="myapp.appspot.com/_ah/upload/assets/demo.doc">Demo Doc</a>`

is there anyway I can fix this without explicitly setting the base url on (or doctoring) each relative path? I've considered, checking the upload status and redirecting the proper page link (without the _ah/upload/somekey) but thats not the ideal approach.

Thanks!

Comment: Save the upload key, and redirect to a success status page. Don't use the _ah urls for rendering content.

Comment: Then it redirects twice right? page posts to the server, returns to the _ah url and we redirect it again. So it refreshes twice for the user. Is there a better way?

Comment: redirect is the best way to do what you're after here I would say.